# Variable parameter in root in route angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

Any ideas how to have variable parameter in route?

Now I have :

> http://<-baseurl->/profile/john

```
.when('/profile/:name', {
                templateUrl: 'views/profile.html',
                controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
            })
```

But I want to do something like this:

> http://<-baseurl->/john/profile

BTW '`/:name/profile`' doesn't work.